# GET request with body for getting token using fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm trying to send GET request with body (i have to send some data for getting token) but i always get an error

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body

const response = fetch('https://login.microsoftonline.com/token', {
    method: 'get',
    body:  {      
        "client_id": "id",
        "client_secret": "secret",
        "grant_type": "grant",
        "scope": "scope"
    },
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
});

const resp = response.body;

console.log(response);
```

Could someone help me with this?

Updated:
Via Postman it works

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you are trying to fetch OAuth token from Azure. The data which you are trying to pass is correct. But you need to call it with POST method. You can't use the body in GET method. Change the method type to POST and check.

Comment: it returns an empty response... i don't understand why it works in Postman (i can send the body in GET)

Comment: share us the error details. It will be helpful for providing solution